# uncaught type error:dom is undefined

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

when trying to find radiobutton id using dom.byId("id") getting the error dom is undefined.

```
require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
    "esri/layers/ImageParameters",
    "esri/dijit/BasemapLayer",
    "esri/dijit/Basemap",
    "esri/dijit/OverviewMap",
    "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils",
    "dojo/parser",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dijit/Toolbar",
    "esri/toolbars/navigation",
    "esri/toolbars/draw",
    "esri/graphic",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/Color",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],
  function(Map,
    ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,
    ImageParameters,
    BasemapLayer,
    Basemap,
    OverviewMap,
    webMercatorUtils,
    parser,
    registry,
    Navigation,
    Draw,
    Graphic,
    SimpleFillSymbol,
    SimpleLineSymbol,
    Color,
    on,
    dom) {

    dojo.parser.parse();
    // Get a reference to the ArcGIS Map class
    var firstBasemapLayer = new esri.dijit.BasemapLayer({
      url: "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer"
    });
    var firstBasemap = new esri.dijit.Basemap({
      id: "Basemap1",
      layers: [firstBasemapLayer],
      opacity: 0.8,
      title: "World topo Map"

    });

    var secondBasemapLayer = new esri.dijit.BasemapLayer({
      url: "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer"
    });
    var secondBasemap = new esri.dijit.Basemap({
      id: "Basemap2",
      layers: [secondBasemapLayer],
      opacity: 0.8,
      title: "oceans"

    });

    var thirdBasemapLayer = new esri.dijit.BasemapLayer({
      url: "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"
    });
    var thirdBasemap = new esri.dijit.Basemap({
      id: "Basemap3",
      layers: [thirdBasemapLayer],
      opacity: 0.8,
      title: "streets"

    });



    // Get a reference to the ArcGIS Map class
    map = new Map("map");
    map.setBasemap(firstBasemap);

    on(dom.byId("radiobasemap1"), "change", updateBaseMap);
    on(dom.byId("radiobasemap2"), "change", updateBaseMap);
    on(dom.byId("radiobasemap3"), "change", updateBaseMap);

    function updateBaseMap() {
      debugger;
      if (dojo.byId("radiobasemap1").checked) {

        map.setBasemap(firstBasemap);

      }
      if (dojo.byId("radiobasemap2").checked) {

        map.setBasemap(secondBasemap);

      }
      if (dojo.byId("radiobasemap3").checked) {

        map.setBasemap(thirdBasemap);

      }
    }



    //Get supported image Parameters
    var imageParameters = new ImageParameters();
    imageParameters.format = "PNG"; //set the image type to PNG24, note default is PNG8.


    var dynamicMap = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://iicss63:6080/arcgis/rest/services/NCAOR_Prasad/WorldShape_Prasad/MapServer", {
      "opacity": 0.5,
      "imageParameters": imageParameters


    });
    map.addLayer(dynamicMap);

    map.on("load", function() {

      //after map loads, connect to listen to mouse move & drag events
      map.on("mouse-move", showCoordinates);
      map.on("mouse-drag", showCoordinates);


    });

    function showCoordinates(evt) {
      // the map is in web mercator but display coordinates in geographic (lat, long)

      //display Map coordinates

    }


    //Display overview Map
    var overviewMapDijit = new esri.dijit.OverviewMap({
        map: map,
        attachTo: "bottom-right",
        visible: true
      },

      dojo.byId("overviewMapDiv"));
    overviewMapDijit.startup();



    //create draw toolbar 
    drawToolbar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map);

    //Create graphic and fill color to graphic   
    var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();

    drawToolbar.on("draw-end", addToMap);

    //add graphic to map
    function addToMap(evt) {
      debugger;
      var graphic = new Graphic(evt.geometry, symbol);
      map.graphics.add(graphic);
    }

    //navigation toolbar

    navToolbar = new esri.toolbars.Navigation(map);
    // var registrytools=dojo.digit.registry;
    on(navToolbar, "onExtentHistoryChange", extentHistoryChangeHandler);

    registry.byId("zoomin").on("click", function() {
      drawToolbar.deactivate();
      navToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Navigation.ZOOM_IN);
    });

    registry.byId("zoomout").on("click", function() {
      drawToolbar.deactivate();
      navToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Navigation.ZOOM_OUT);
    });

    registry.byId("zoomfullext").on("click", function() {
      drawToolbar.deactivate();
      navToolbar.zoomToFullExtent();
    });

    registry.byId("zoomprev").on("click", function() {
      drawToolbar.deactivate();
      navToolbar.zoomToPrevExtent();
    });

    registry.byId("zoomnext").on("click", function() {
      drawToolbar.deactivate();
      navToolbar.zoomToNextExtent();
    });

    registry.byId("pan").on("click", function() {
      drawToolbar.deactivate();
      navToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Navigation.PAN);
    });


    registry.byId("deactivate").on("click", function() {
      drawToolbar.deactivate();
      navToolbar.deactivate();

    });
    registry.byId("drawRectangle").on("click", function() {
      navToolbar.deactivate();
      drawToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.RECTANGLE);

    });


    function extentHistoryChangeHandler() {

      registry.byId("zoomprev").disabled = navToolbar.isFirstExtent();
      registry.byId("zoomnext").disabled = navToolbar.isLastExtent();
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 4):

The array of module IDs passed to `require` includes `"dijit/form/Button"` but there's no alias for it in the callback.

Add `Button,` between `Color,` and `on,` in the arguments for your function that's passed to require and `dom` will exist and have the `byId` method you're trying to use.

Answer (score 2):

You are also missing the alias for "dijit/Toolbar".

A more basic programming note is that you don't need

```
dojo.parser.parse();
var firstBasemapLayer = new esri.dijit.BasemapLayer({
var firstBasemap = new esri.dijit.Basemap({
```

when using AMD style. You just need

```
parser.parse();
var firstBasemapLayer = new BasemapLayer({
var firstBasemap = new Basemap({
```

I would suggest reading [this blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/10/14/the-abcs-of-amd/) about AMD pattern