# Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

while clicking on the button on.click event is not fired and getting error "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined",how to solve this issue.

Simple Map
    
    
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        background-color: #FFF;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
      }
    
    
    
      var map,navToolbar;

```
  require(["esri/map",
           "dojo/dom",
           "dojo/on",
           "dijit/form/Button",
           "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map,dom,on,parser,registry) {
      map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "streets",  
      center: [72, 25.75], 
      zoom: 5
    });
    //navToolbar = new Navigation(map);
      //on(navToolbar, "onExtentHistoryChange", extentHistoryChangeHandler);

    dijit.registry.byId("clickMe").on("click",showMessage);
    function showMessage(){
     alert("Hello")
    }       
});

</script>
```

**Click Me**

Comment: Could be a couple of things. Can you show what the html for the button element looks like? It should of course have id="clickMe" as one of its attributes and will need to be of data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"

Answer (score 2):

you are missing several modules in your `require()` call, so the mapping of the aliases in your callback are incorrect.

```
require([
  "esri/map",
  "dojo/dom",
  "dojo/on",
  "dojo/parser", // < this one
  "dijit/registry", // < and this one
  "dijit/form/Button",
  "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map, dom, on, parser, registry, Button) {
```

afterwards, you need to use your alias when you call `on` and ensure the corresponding `<div>` is present.

```
registry.byId("clickMe").on("click",showMessage);
// ...
<div id="clickMe"></div>
```

see [this old blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/10/14/the-abcs-of-amd/) of mine for more information.

#### related threads

- [Uncaught TypeError: webMercatorUtils.webMercatorToGeographic is not a function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171021/uncaught-typeerror-webmercatorutils-webmercatortogeographic-is-not-a-function)
- [uncaught type error:dom is undefined](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170525/uncaught-type-errordom-is-undefined)